# Memory leak in PageViewer that contain webview on Android

Tags: android, memory-leaks, webview

I use a `ViewPager` in my app. Every Page contains a `WebView` and some `ImageView`. I know that the `WebView` is the most critical view.

When I rotate the screen the `Activity` isn't destroyed.
In the `destroyItem()` I use the following code:

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)((LimitScrollView)((RelativeLayout)view).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View locView = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (locView.getTag() !=null && ((String)(locView.getTag())).equals(ADAPTER_TAG_WEBVIEW)){
            FrameLayout webViewFrame = (FrameLayout)locView;
            WebViewSub webView = (WebViewSub ) webViewFrame .getChildAt(0);
            webView.destroy();
            webView = null;
            webViewFrame.removeAllViews();
        }
    }
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
}
```

I tried to remove all `WebView` from the `onDestroy()` method in the `Activity`, but after the rotation I have two instances of `Activity` in the MAT.
If I don't use `WebView` I have one activity after the rotation.

Comment: What does MAT show you is holding onto the second activity?

Comment: The second (garbage) activity contain ImageView, frameLayout and a webkit Callback. I don't know how to remove the webkit Callback. This is the problem?

Comment: What does MAT show you is holding onto the second activity? Note that I did not ask what the second activity is holding.

Comment: In the "incoming refrences" I see these UI elements. If I don't use the webView in the PageViewer, this problem does not come up. I tested it.

Comment: To determine what is holding onto an object in MAT, you use "Paths to GC roots". You may wish to watch the Google I|O video on using MAT with Android: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Comment: Thank you the answer. I try to solve the problem to the "Paths to GC roots" option.